# How to turn on Fused Multiply Add in GCC for ARM processor

Tags: gcc, arm

In my C program, I want the processor to compute a*b +c using FMADD instruction rather than MUL and ADD. How do I specify this to the compiler to do this. Also I would like to see FMADD instruction in the assembly code after compile.

gcc version 4.9.2
ARM v7 Processor

Comment: Use function `fma` from math.h, and make sure you pass a suitable -march flag to the compiler.

Comment: Ok. It works. Is it possible to use FP_CONTRACT and usual *, + operators instead of fma ? I tried #pragma STDC FP_CONTRACT ON. It didn't work

Comment: Depending on your -march and -ffp-contract flags, you may not even need any pragma. Gcc does the contraction by default on targets that have native support for fma.

Comment: Does adding `-ffast-math` help at all, in terms of getting the compiler to generate this from adds and multiplies?

Comment: I don't believe -ffast-math helps there.

Comment: Note:  `FMADD` is an aarch64 instruction and I don't think it is found in the 32-bit ARM.  You should use the tag [tag:arm64] if you specifically want this instructions (and are using a 64-bit mode).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have one of the following FPUs,

- vfpv4
- vfpv4-d16
- fpv4-sp-d16
- fpv5-sp-d16
- fpv5-d16
- neon-vfpv4
- fp-armv8
- neon-fp-armv8
- crypto-neon-fp-armv8

You must use the *hard-float* ABI option.

[An example with integers](https://godbolt.org/g/wCs8WJ).
[An example with floats](https://godbolt.org/g/Z7wBnC).

You shouldn't need to specify any special function calls; the compiler will use the instruction if it finds they are beneficial.

---

The code in *arm.c* responsible for generation is,

```
case FMA:
  if (TARGET_32BIT && TARGET_HARD_FLOAT && TARGET_FMA)
```

With TARGET_FMA being a version '4' or better FPU.